# How to reproduce a forum/twitter-like UI on Winform

Tags: c#, html, winforms, user-interface, forum

As a classic forum, threads and replys are displayed on a page, with dark and light and dark and light backcolor.

I am trying to write a client of a forum on windows using winform. It is

At first, I have tried this way:

1. Add a big panel to the form, let's call it the PARENT PANEL.
2. Add small panels to the big panel like this:

   ```
       panel1.Visible = false;
       for (int i=0; i<5;i++)
       {
           Panel parent = new Panel();
           parent.Height = 800;
           Random ra = new Random();
           TextBox p = new TextBox();
           p.Text = "fehsuifq";
           p.Multiline = true;
           p.WordWrap = true;
           p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
           parent.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(ra.Next(0, 254), ra.Next(0, 254), ra.Next(0, 254));
           p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
           p.ReadOnly = true;
           p.TabStop = false;
           p.BackColor = this.BackColor;
           parent.Controls.Add(p);
           parent.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
           panel1.Controls.Add(parent);
       }
       panel1.Visible = true;
   ```

Every panel(tenicially, a control) displays a thread's text and images and others details(like authors or avator).
Images are not shown until it is clicked.
when the image is clicked, it is loaded and the controls's height will change as result.
The PARENT PANEL will contains hundreds of these controls since there will be so many threads. It is and have to be scrollable, obviously.

**But if I put a textbox in the control, the scroll wheel no longer work on the PARENT PANEL**.If I use a label, it is not selectable.

I think this way can't be more stupid, completely.

So I am looking for a better to do this job, to display hundreds or even thousands threads/replys on winform, which is:

1. the height is dynamic, because the images inside will not load until it is clicked.
2. **The text inside** is selectable  (I edited this just to disambiguate)
3. the PARENT PANEL can response to the mouse's wheel, just like twitter, forums.

So that I can use my scroll wheel to browse all the replys at one time. The loading is a background work.

[image]
Look at the picture, when the text is selected, the whole panel is still response to the wheel(just like normal webPage). This is a uwp app and I am not sure if winform can do this.

Comment: have you considered just using a browser control and doing it via HTML?

Comment: I would mainly ask why would you want to do that with WinForms..

Comment: @Ctznkane525 no, because I can't control the image's loading. besides I need to be more controllable. For example, I right click on the image, the menu is my own rather than browsers.

Comment: @Avi Meltser That's obvious I don't know another language.:D Besides, on windows, what can be better to do this?

Comment: Another reason that I won't use a big browser is that, once a thread is change/blocked, all will be refreshed. I will have rules to decide the threads to display or not, or no longer displayed, and so on.

Comment: windows forms has a limit on the number of controls on can have inside the application...putting tens of thosands of controls on the page definitely won't be an option...youll notice for example with a DataGridView...the controls are only created for the row in edit mode...and then disposed of

Comment: @T.Worm This has WPF/MVVM written all over it. WPF+MVVM is a steep learning curve, but if you're at all willing to contemplate another way of doing it (I understand if you're not), I'd suggest giving it a whirl. Knowing WPF, I wouldn't touch winforms for anything -- and not at all because winforms sucks; I still remember how great winforms was when I switched over from MFC.

Comment: A Panel is not selectable, usually. You can build a custom one, setting `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse | ControlStyles.Selectable | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);` in its constuctor. it will become selectable (and *buffered*). Add `ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |                             ControlStyles.UserPaint` if you want to paint over it (avoids flickering, to an extent). Anyway, I agree with the others: WinForms was not built (nor *enhanced* in any updates) for this.

Comment: @Jimi I want a proper sub-control that display text. text is selectable and can't effect the parent-panel's scrolling, just like webpage. label will not effect the wheel but the text can't be selected by which time textbox is the opposite, selectable but disable the wheel to the parent panel. I was ambiguous before. I think you may know how to make such a custom control.  BTW: 【parent Panel】 contains hundrerds of 【custom controls】(dynamically added to 【parent Panel】, custom controls contains texts(selectable), buttons, images etc.. this is my stupid design. Better design is always appreciated.

Comment: You can use the Selectable panel, add a RichTextBox with `HideSelection = false`, `ReadOnly = true`, `BorderStyle = None`. On MouseUp: `richTextBox1.Parent.Focus();`. You can then select the (optionally, multicolored) text and the Panel will scroll. You should use a WebBrowser anyway.

Comment: @Jimi It really work. You are incredible. But another problem. When I click the Textbox, it will effect the scrollbar of the parent panel. (The system want to show the custom panel, make it in the top of the panel shown, if it is shown partly before. But in the webpage, no matter how you click, the relative position never change until using the wheel. Can this be fixed?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. The custom, selectable Panel is the Parent control, the one where you set `AutoScroll = true`. Add to it all the controls it can handle until it explodes :)

Comment: @Jimi https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4N2S.jpg after clicked, the scrollbar changed. Besides this is still stupid. What will you do if you want to make things like the image mention in the post? A fully webpage-behavior-like. Is there another better way? (don't just mention wpf, since I know nothing about wpf this may be meaningless.)

Comment: As you can see, I didn't mention WPF, which is not build for this either. WebBrowsers are. The rendering of elements is limited to what you can see, plus what has already been cached, to ease the scrolling. You could do this with both WinForms and WPF. But neither has the caching behaviour nor  the rendering logic already built in. Maybe WPF's Flow Document, but it's heavy nonetheless. You'ld have to build your own caching strategy from scratch.

Comment: @Jimi Is there a way to fix the scrollbar problem? Which means no matter what I do, only the wheel can scroll the parent panel, like a webpage, nothing can scroll a page no matter what we do.